# Reproduce Asset pipeline bugs that occur in production env, NOT development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In Rails 3.2.3 app, i encounter an error, similar to the following when deployed to heroku:-

```
Started GET "/" for 59.xx.xx.xx at 2012-xx-xx xx:xx:xx +0000
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 62ms

ActionView::Template::Error (style.css isn't precompiled)
```

so, it turns out: the stylesheet is not getting precompiled for some reason(Yes, I tried assets:precompile).

to fix this, first I have to reproduce this error on my development box, so I may know what is wrong.

Hence, my question is:

**how to I reproduce this problem on my machine?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Rails only precompiles `application.js` and `application.css` (and all non-JS/CSS assets). If you want it to precompile another file (which you need to do if you use `javascript_include_tag`, et al. in your layout), you need to add your file to the list of precompiled files.

Open `config/environments/production.rb`, and there should be a commented out line that begins with `config.assets.precompile` and an explanation above it. Uncomment this line and change it to:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(stylesheets/style.css)
```

(use the path to style.css if that's not the right directory).

To reproduce this on development, you would have to modify development.rb to have all the same asset settings as production.rb.

[Edit]

As you've found, you can start the built-in Rails server in another environment from the command line--however, this effects everything (class reloading, database connections, email settings, etc.) in addition to the asset pipeline settings, so it can sometimes be deceiving at best (unanticipated side-effects) and dangerous at worst (accidentally sending emails to users). Not that it's not useful, just be careful. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run production environment on my local dev machine, by simply specifying the environment while starting the server

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

And was able to reproduce the issue. Didn't knew it was so trivial to switch between development & production environments in rails

Comment: `rails s -e production` would do the same